# openssl s_client no cipher match

Tags: openssl

I get the following error when trying to set the cipher in `openssl s_client`:

```
# openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.3:8443 -cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Error with command: "-cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
140230972122240:error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2549:
```

When I look up this error in Google, it says that the cipher is missing from the list reported by `openssl ciphers`. However, this is not the case:

```
# openssl ciphers | sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

This error is not a function of the server configuration, as it is printed even if I change the `-connect` IP address to something bogus. So evidently the problem is happening before `s_client` even attempts to connect to the server.

What does this error message mean, given that it seems unrelated to `openssl ciphers`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLSv1.3 changed the way ciphersuites work quite significantly. As a result ciphersuites defined for TLSv1.2 and below do not work in TLSv1.3 and vice versa. For this reason OpenSSL handles them separately internally as well and they are configured in different ways - even though "on the wire" the list of TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 ciphersuites get merged. The `openssl ciphers` command reports the merged list of TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 ciphersuites.

TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 is actually a TLSv1.3 ciphersuite:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | grep TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Therefore you need to use a different command line option in s_client to use that ciphersuite:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.3:8443 -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Although actually the above command will send the combined list of default TLSv1.2 ciphersuites as well as the above TLSv1.3 ciphersuite. If you *only* want that one ciphersuite then you will additionally need to disable protocol versions below TLSv1.3:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.3:8443 -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 -tls1_3
```

Note however that the ciphersuite you are interested in is in the default set of TLSv1.3 ciphersuites so if you don't set any other TLSv1.3 ciphersuite configuration it will get sent anyway.

Comment: That is really interesting because I have TLS_AES256_GCM_SHA384 working just fine in TLSv1.2, and that is more bits than AES-128. But I see what you're saying... I'll try with TLSv1.3...

Comment: Yes, this worked! Note that I had to change the server from Python to C too (I guess that could be another question...) Thank you.

Comment: And this `ciphersuites` business seems to exist in the C API as well. There is `SSL_set_cipher_list` versus `SSL_set_ciphersuites`. How lovely.

Answer (score 0):

During handshake the client and server negotiate which cipher should be used. Looks like the the server is not having the the cipher you are specified in the s_client.
From openssl ciphers man page I see TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 listed only in TLS1.3 version, so its possible that the server you are trying to connect supports protocol till 1.2 only.You can take look at the handshake data by putting a sniffer between your client and server to confirm whats actually happening.

Comment: Re: "Looks like the the server is not having the the cipher you are specified"... But if that is the case, then why is this message printed *before* s_client attempts to connect to the serer (as noted in the question)?

Comment: Right, the error could be before it goes for connection. It could be due to openssl version you are using, with openssl1.1.1-pre8 I can see it works with this command, but I will suggest you downloading latest version and try with that.

Answer (score 0):

The `tls-cipher` has been changed to `tls-ciphersuites` for `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, so change the following line in the config file(.ovpn):

```
tls-cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

to

```
tls-ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```